# How to create an empty RowMatrix in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Is there any way to create an empty RowMatrix in Apache Spark. I have tried the following

```
double[] empty = new double[0];
Vector vector = Vectors.dense(empty);
```

But I can not create a JavaRDD of Vector from vector, so that I can create the RowMatrix out of it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Looking from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix, its not possible to create an empty RowMatrix

So the constructor requires passing a RDD<Vector> as one of the calling way

I tried a sample in spark-shell in Scala. Hope this helps

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix
val data = sc.parallelize(Array(Array[Double](1,2,3,4),Array[Double](2,3,4,5),Array[Double](3,4,5,6))).map(x=> Vectors.dense(x))
val rowMatrix: RowMatrix = new RowMatrix(data)
```

Now we can perform required operation on the rowMatrix which is type RowMatrix while data is RDD<Vector>

Also Vectors.dense require a list of Arrays as Double so we might require to case the initial array as Double if its not already.